# How to create collaboration diagrams for a Groovy program?

Tags: groovy, doxygen

I'm wondering if there is a way to generate collaboration diagrams for a Groovy program in the same way that Doxygen does for Java etc. I tried running Doxygen but it doesn't seem to be able to parse Groovy files (or did I get it wrong?).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html) Groovy is *not* supported (supported languages are C, C++, C#, Objective-C, IDL, Java, VHDL, PHP, Python, Tcl, Fortran, and D). According to question 12 of the [FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html) you will have to modify the doxygen source if you are trying to documentation a non-supported language.

If Groovy is similar to one of these languages (I have never used Groovy) then you can try using one these existing parsers to attempt to parse Groovy source code. To do this you need to configure doxygen to run the correct parser on files with the `.groovy` extension (is this the correct extension for groovy files?). You can do this by setting the [`EXTENSION_MAPPING`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extension_mapping) configuration option in the doxygen configuration file to

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING += groovy=Java
```

This tells doxygen to use the Java parser on any file with the extension `.groovy`.

Comment: My second paragraph was a stab in the dark, ultimately *According to question 12 of the FAQ you will have to modify the doxygen source if you are trying to document a non-supported language.*

Answer (score 0):

You can generate diagrams from inside IntelliJ. They look like this:

[image]

---

**Edit**

I think it is quite hard (maybe impossible) to create correct collaboration diagrams in groovy since it is a dynamic language with duck typing.

How would these classes be illustrated in a collaboration graph:

```
class Cage {
    private def bird

    Cage(bird) {
        this.bird = bird
    }

    def shake() {
        bird.sing()
    }
}

class Dog {
    def sing() {
        println 'Woof'
    }
}


class Main {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Cage cage = new Cage(new Dog())
        cage.shake()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a class diagram (showing the class hierarchy), and not a collaboration diagram (showing the flow in the program). Nice diagram though :)

Comment: @uzilan You are right. I updated with my thoughts on the collaboration part.